# gcc iostream not found in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, iostream

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10 here for a class, and I have to write a pretty simple program just to prove that we remember things from basic programming. It just has to be a tic tac toe game, basically.

Now that's all well and good but every time I've tried to compile it, it says it can't find iostream. (error message below)

```
cameron@ubuntu:~/Documents/ECE 2220$ gcc -Wall prog1.c
prog1.c:1:20: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
 #include <iostream>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
```

Now, maybe I have to use g++, but that compiles it as c++, right? Which doesn't work at all for my purposes, since it's for a class in c. I have installed build-essential, and thought that that could be the issue, but after a reinstall, it has the same issue. I can't find anything else quite like this. Does anyone have any idea how to fix the issue?

Comment: If you're trying to program in C, why are you using `iostream`?

Comment: @carl I'm obviously missing something stupid here. It's just the way we've been shown to do it. This sort of code and this manner of compiling it has been working for the past year.. so what's different about this machine? and now that you say that, that is a good question.. here is what hello world looks like in the format we've been using

#include <iostream>

int main() {
 printf("Hello world.");
 return 0;
}

Comment: That hello world should not compile with gcc in a .c file anywhere.  you're sure it wasn't `#include <stdio.h>` instead, or possibly your file had a .cpp or .cc or a .C extension ?

Comment: @nos I went back and looked at some old lab files.. this is by far the stupidest mistake I could've made. That's exactly what I did, I should've called stdio.h instead. I've been learning both and got mixed up and somehow didn't catch on until after posting here. I appreciate everyone's help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should compile with `g++`. gcc invokes C compiler.

And consider giving another extension to your source file. C++ source files usually have extension `.cc`, `.cpp` or `.C` (capital).

And yes, you have to compile it as C++. You cannot use classes and `<iostream>` in C.